# How do I infer nested argument type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using typescript generics and I'd like to infer the type of `fn` aka `P`, however it's not working as I'd expect.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBQB0RcATgOYDOAXFHAHYgDaAugJQ4B8tDUAULwEs6wCCQBm6aACUA9gFcRAHl5QoAFSgQAHiLoATCrEQp0GXlwDeKqGLo01vAL78xcummACZdKCXkioZVUABU0dCH1DeCRUTAAaaykw3QMoWQUIRWCOc3wwOGAACzo4AFsIGgpgEiEyOKhC%20j0EURopditVEghgORIfRv0WkgJbJ340byqoLRxffwg8AHIAekKBJfqLWxo8EvLK6tr2bC4AA3WoABILfYhHM8dWXhWV1VUAPQB%20fiA)

Here's the code:

```
type Callback = (...args: any[]) => any 

interface Route<
  T extends Callback
> {
  fn: T
}

function route <
  P extends Callback,
  R extends Route<P>
> (pathname: string, handler: R) {
  return handler.fn
}

const x = route('/hi', {fn: (name: string) => `hi ${name}`})
//    ^?
```

I'd expect `x` to return the type `(name: string) => string`, but instead it's returning `Callback`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized I can remove `R` and call `Route<P>` and it works. I suppose this makes sense.

```
function route <
  P extends Callback,
> (pathname: string, handler: Route<P>) {
  return handler.fn
}
```

The rational is the thing you don't know should be the thing extended. The thing you "know" shouldn't.

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it is

Comment: @Dimava chill I can't accept it until tomorrow